# How to have drawable animation in my canvas?

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, imageview

i want to animate an object and i found out that there is a easier way called **animation drawable** but my problem is that all tutorials that i had found uses only an `imageview`.

now my question is how to convert `imageview into a bitmap` so I can make my object in my ondraw method move or animate?

codes:

```
mAnimLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_header);
mAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mAnimLogo.getDrawable();
mAnimation.start();
```

then on my ondraw method:

```
lvl1_portal1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.add_portal1);
lvl1_portal1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(lvl1_portal1, Bitwidth,
            Bitheight, true);
canvas.drawBitmap(lvl1_portal1, (mazeFinishX1 * totalCellWidth)
            + (cellWidth / 20), (mazeFinishY1 * totalCellHeight)
            + (cellWidth / 20), ball);
```

Comment: See Drawable.draw(Canvas) method

Comment: Sir @pskink the ondraw method code is posted above.

Comment: You can draw **any** Drawable on your Canvas using Drawable.draw(Canvas) method

Comment: sir it is also possible to have animation drawable on that method?

Comment: Yes,  AnimationDrawable extends Drawable so you can call draw(Canvas) method